# Static class member shows confusing syntax error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is my project setup:

Main.hpp

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MAIN_HPP
#define MAIN_HPP

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include "Util/Cache.hpp"

#include "SampInternal.hpp"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);

#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Main.hpp"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);

    if (dwReason != DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        return FALSE;

    return (CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &SampInternal::Initialize, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0);
}
```

SampInternal.hpp (Foo.hpp before edit)

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SAMPINTERNAL_HPP
#define SAMPINTERNAL_HPP

#include "Main.hpp"

#define D3D9_NAME                           "d3d9"
#define SAMP_NAME                           "samp"

#define D3D9_DLL                            "d3d9.dll"
#define SAMP_DLL                            "samp.dll"

class SampInternal
{

public:

    static DWORD APIENTRY Initialize(LPVOID lpArgs);

private:

    static Cache<HMODULE> s_moduleCache;

};

#endif
```

SampInternal.cpp

```
#include "SampInternal.hpp"

Cache<HMODULE> SampInternal::s_moduleCache;

DWORD APIENTRY SampInternal::Initialize(LPVOID lpArgs)
{

    return 0;
}
```

Cache.hpp

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CACHE_HPP
#define CACHE_HPP

#include "../Main.hpp"

template<typename T>
class Cache
{

public:

    void Add(std::string name, T value);
    T Get(std::string name);

private:

    std::map<std::string, T> m_storage;;

};

template<typename T>
void Cache<T>::Add(std::string name, T value)
{
    m_storage[name] = value;
}

template<typename T>
T Cache<T>::Get(std::string name)
{
    if (m_storage.find(name) != m_storage.end())
        return m_storage[name];

    return nullptr;
}

#endif
```

(Cache.cpp is empty - only `#include "Cache.hpp"`)

I'm a beginner in C++ but I can't see any errors here.
The compiler (using Visual Studio 2015) outputs me:

`Syntax Error: Missing ';' before '<'`
`Unexpected token before ';'`

Both on the line `static Cache<HMODULE> s_moduleCache;`

Sorry if this looks trivial to you, but I don't know whats the problem here.

Comment: Included the necessary header for `HMODULE`?

Comment: You do include the header file where `Cache` is defined before the definition of the `Foo` class?  Other than that it's really hard to say anything without seeing more code, can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Yep, windows.h is included.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg There isn't really much more to show.
I got a main.cpp with a entry point but thats it.

Comment: @namespace *There isn't really much more to show* -- If I took the code you posted and attempted to compile it, I would get a whole host of errors.  Please post a *complete* example, including headers.

Comment: Did you include `Cache` before `Foo`?

Comment: I updated my post - `Foo` got renamed to `SampInternal`

Comment: While I can see many *potential* problems with the code you show, there's nothing explicitly wrong if you just include the correct headers in the correct order. That's why you need to show us more, and if the code is not much more then please post all of it.

Comment: Could you tell me this potential problems? I want to learn, thanks :)

Comment: Use `#pragma once` or `#ifndef...` but not both. (Has nothing to do with your problem)

Comment: Exceptions are thrown, at runtime. Compilation error messages are printed, at compile time. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: Tip: Listen to what ZDF said; you can either enclose your entire header files between `#ifndef #define ... #endif` or use `#pragma once`. They are slightly different but they both do the same thing.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Yes, I removed the include guard and only use #pragma once, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a normal *circular inclusion dependency* problem to me: `Cache.hpp` needs `Main.hpp` which needs `SampInternal.hpp` which needs `Cache.hpp` ... etc. and so on.

The simplest way to break this circle (as far as I can see) is to not include `Main.hpp` in the `Cache.hpp` file. In the `Cache.hpp` file include the files it needs explicitly, e.g. `<map>` and `<string>`.

Comment: Oh you are right, that works.
I thought by defining a variable `#define CACHE_HPP` I can pass this problem. Is there a way to still have one file for all my includes that gets included everywhere?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I got it: I forward declared Cache in my SampInternal header file.

Comment: Yes it is called a standard header file usually named `stdafx.h` where all of your common includes would go such as any of the standard headers and it is also used in conjunction with `stdafx.cpp`. Now if you add these yourself to a blank project, you will have to go into the project's settings and change it to use standard header, but on the `stdafx.cpp` you will have to set its flag to create a precompiled header. This option is usually there for you when you create a new win32 console or win32 window application where you haven't selected a blank project.

Comment: To add to that if you know that a specific class object will be the only one to reference another specific header then include that header in the class file instead of the standard. Things that gets used everywhere such as `std::string`, std::vector`, `std::fstream` etc., should be in your standard header. Now if you do use standard headers, it will be required to include the `stdafx.h` file in every `*.cpp` file. Also; it is also important to not have `#include "stdafx.h"` in your class's header files because of circular inclusion; you should only need them in their implementation file.